# Returning recursively the same function based on parentheses number

Tags: javascript, recursion

I saw last days this question about Javascript, that a function should return back some values based on the number of parentheses calls in the function.

```
console.log(f() == 1); //->true
console.log(f()() == 3); //->true
console.log(f()()() == 6); //->true
... //and so on 10,15,21...
```

I came up with the following code:

```js
function f() {
    f.count++;
    return f;
};

f.count=0;
f.toString = function(){
 console.log(f.count);
 return f.count;
};

console.log(f() == 1); // true
console.log(f()() == 3); //3
console.log(f()()() == 6); //6
```

But this will break if, for instance, I call:

```
f();
console.log(f() == 1); // true
console.log(f()() == 3); //3
console.log(f()()() == 6); //6
```

Which I understand why. However, my question is: **how can I make this recursive in the way that the function can tell how many parentheses were used and to be independent of the other calls?**

So for instance, when I'm saying `f()` to get 1 and if I say `f(); f();` to get 1 and 1. Not 1 and 2.

I know that maybe it has to do with the scope of the variable (I was trying to follow this: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)), but for my example, my tries were without success.

Comment: Return a new function instead of the same one.

Comment: but then will not be recursive, or what you have in mind?

Comment: this function is not properly recursive. It returns itself and you call it again, but it is not defined in terms of itself. Moreover, this works by side-effect: it modifies the field count, which is not a good programming practice.

Comment: If you need a function that calls itself `n` times, it's more natural to use a parameter `n` instead of calling it with n `()`, no?

Comment: As said above, this isn't recursivity but some kind of weird currying. You should tell us exactly what you seek : solving a specific problem or fit this syntax ?

Comment: @RobertoTrani I know, but these were the requirements, so I have to work with what I have. And as a side note, these whole question/requirements were not mine, but I just found the question challenging and fun to find an answer to it.

Comment: @topheman a better solution than mine in the direction of recursive call or something like that

Comment: @Edwin: Your original function wasn’t recursive either, but I’m pretty sure that isn’t an actual requirement.

Comment: @Ryan I was just interested if maybe can be done in a recursive way, let's say you add an `n` argument to `f` and check if is undefined or not and go on from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a new counter every time `f` is called and then return a different function, so that that one does not reset the counter.

Also, in ES6 you can use `this` to keep track of the count as a primitive number:

```js
function f() {
    const g = f.bind((+this || 0)+1);
    g.toString = () => (+this+1) * (+this+2)/2 || 1;
    return g;
}

console.log('' + f()); // 1
console.log('' + f()()); // 3
console.log('' + f()()()); // 6
console.log('' + f()()); // 3
```

Comment: great snippet. There is no need to coerce `this` though (`+this`).

Comment: Thanks. The coercion is still necessary in sloppy mode, where `this` is the `window` object and gets coerced to string with the next `+ 1` acting as concatenation.

Comment: clarification/confirmation please:  if `this` is the `window` object then `+this` becomes `NaN`, not a string nor the string `"NaN"`. Thus, the first call resolves to: `const g =  f.bind(1)`. Wait! `bind` returns a function so the primitive `1` is cast (wrapped) to `Number`. Thus `Number` - not a numeric literal and not a number-as-string  - is the `this` of all subsequent calls.

Comment: In ES6 `this` remains a primitive; it is no longer cast to an object as in ES5.

Comment: nice snippet, let me check if I got some stuff right from it. When you did `+this || 0` you did that just to assure that `this` is  gonna be `0` or the `this` value until that point parsed (in this case) to int? then the `toString` is just the logic to get different values for the number of parentheses

Comment: When `f` is called (the initial call), `this` will be the `window` object (sloppy mode) or `undefined` (strict mode). In both cases, `+this` will be `NaN` which is falsy, so then the `|| 0` kicks in. The same with the `toString` function where the expression will be `NaN` again and `|| 1` kicks in. Once `this` is numerical, then `+this` is a no-op.